# Как обработать Exception и сделать реконнект?

Tags: java, исключения, url, proxy

Имеется метод, который коннектится по заданному url через прокси.

```java
public void myGetContent(int startRange, int endRange, String threadName) throws Exception{

        //..некоторый код        

        ProxyParser proxyParser = new ProxyParser();
        //Массив с ip и портами
        ArrayList<String> proxyList = proxyParser.getProxyRowsArray();

        //устанавливаем значение proxy
        setProxy(proxyList.get(0), Integer.parseInt(proxyList.get(1)));

        int i = startRange;

        while (i < endRange){
            Thread.sleep(3000);

            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            URL website = new URL("http://my-url.com/...&DocNumber" + i);

            //Открываем соединение через прокси
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) website.openConnection(proxy);

            ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(connection.getInputStream());
            FileOutputStream fos =
                    new FileOutputStream(+ i  /*НАЗВАНИЕ СОХРАНЯЕМОГО ДОКУМЕНТА */
                            + ".html");
            fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
            //Размер загруженного файла
            size = fos.getChannel().size();
            fos.close();

            //.....некоторый код
            i ++;
        }
    }
```

Как сделать реконнект в случае возникновения TimeoutException'а или какого-либо другого исключения при наличии ArrayList'а со значениями ip и port?

Comment: Может стоит попробовать try..catch?

Comment: Можно попробовать Closable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать заключить блок кода подключения в цикл:

```
boolean isConnect = false;
while(!isConnect) {
    try {
        // код подключения, где может возникнуть TimeoutException

        isConnect = true; // до сюда не дойдёт, если возникло исключение
    catch(TimeoutException ex) {
        // возможно сообщение о повторной попытки подключения
        isConnect = false;
    }
}
```

Тогда из цикла не выйдет, пока не произойдёт подключение, также здесь можно задать количество попыток.